# EFI System Partition not usable error when I try to upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade

When I try to upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04 I get a EFI System Partition. I'm extremely confused and I tried sudo mount /boot/efi and it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Can you please describe what error you get ?

Comment: Can you post images of your problem?